# Parse error while creating hive table using shell variables

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive

I am trying to create a hive table with below commands but getting error as

> cannot recognize input near ')' 'PARTITIONED' 'BY' in column type

```
USE ${hiveconf:DBNAME} ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${hiveconf:TBNAME} (${hiveconf:ts}) PARTITIONED BY(timest string) ROW 
FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",";
```

The above script is called using

```
hive -hiveconf ts=$layout1 -hiveconf TBNAME=$TABLENAME -hiveconf DBNAME=$DATABASE -hiveconf env=$environment -f sqlqueryfile
```

any ideas why it is failing.

the two config file variables are

```
TABLENAME=testingmultiple
layout1="TP string, KEY_NM string, KEY_CD string, YR_MO double, POS double"
```

Comment: Typo? `--hiveconf`

Comment: Also, Hive CLI is deprecated. Beeline is preferred

Answer (score 0):

Use wrapping while passing ts: refer below command:-

```
  hive -hiveconf "ts=$layout1" -hiveconf TBNAME=$TABLENAME -hiveconf DBNAME=$DATABASE -hiveconf env=$environment -f sqlqueryfile
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish , However what is the concept behind wrapping it? We are not wrapping any other variable

Comment: It is needed when your variable have space or quotes.